# Django - How can I print a record by console?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 records in my database then I'm trying to print it like that:

```
instance = People.objects.all()
for item in instance:
    qs_name = item.name
    qs_user = item.user
    qs_password = item.password
    print qs_name,qs_user,qs_password
```

I'm getting something like this:

> Kevin kjhf98 896687
>
> Joe jwd22 336558

I want to store in a variable a single record, is that even possible?

for example:

```
Person_1 = Kevin kjhf98 896687
```

then if I print `Person_1` I'll get only

> Kevin kjhf98 896687

I need this for something else that's why I'm asking for help..

any help would be apreciate!! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [values_list](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
instance = People.objects.all().values_list('name', 'user__username', 'password')

for item in instance:
    print(item)
```

output:

```
(Kevin, kjhf98, 896687)
(Joe, jwd22, 336558)
```

or if you want just string:

```
for item in instance:
    print(' '.join(str(i) for i in item))
```

output:

```
Kevin kjhf98 896687
Joe jwd22 336558
```

Comment: That's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i suppose you can do this.

```
Person_1 = "{} {} {}".format(item.name,item.user,item.password)
```